# How to fire ActiveTabChanged event of ajax:Tabcontainer conditionally

Tags: asp.net, event-handling, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have an `ajax:TabContainer` on my web form and have 2 `TabPanel`'s in `TabContainer`.
I need to call server side methods when the user clicks on the second `TabPanel`. When the user clicks on first `TabPanel` it'll do noting and when the user clicks on the second `TabPanel` it'll fire some server side code.

For that I tried to use ActiveTabChanged and OnClientActiveTabChanged.

### Server Side Code

```
void TabContainer1_ActiveTabChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Code goes here
}
```

### JavaScript Code

```
function fireChangedEvent(sender, e) {
    if (sender.get_activeTabIndex() == 1) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

But it is not working every time user clicks on any tab it'll fire `TabContainer1_ActiveTabChanged`.
Can any one guide me on how I can fire this event when I need not every time when the user clicks on any tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found a solution of this problem. We can use update panel and triggers for conditional calling of server side method.
Solution posted by `Matt Berseth`

[How To: Lazy-load TabPanel's within the AjaxControlToolkit's TabContainer Control](http://web.archive.org/web/20130512073901/http://mattberseth.com/blog/2007/07/how_to_lazyload_tabpanels_with.html)

Now my problem is solved.

Comment: It's very simple. Check answer from Roshe below.

Comment: Thanks for that link

Answer (score 2):

The TabContainer works like any dropdownlist, checkbox etc.. as it needs the "autopostback" parameter set to true :

```
<asp:TabContainer ID="TabContainer1" runat="server" ActiveTabIndex="2" Width="920px"
                                    AutoPostBack="True">
```

Comment: Plz read my question care fully.I'm not asking how can i call `postback` event on when user clicks on any tab.I'm asking how can i call this event conditionally.I'm able to call this event.But i need to call this event only when user clicks on second tab.Now i think you can under stand what actually i needed.And by the way i got a solution and already posted that solution.

Comment: Thanks. The **AutoPostBack="True"** did it for me

Answer (score 1):

If I got it correctly, you can do this by specifying TabIndex for your asp:TabPanel.

```
<asp:TabPanel id="tab1" TabIndex=1>
<asp:TabPanel id="tab2" TabIndex=2>
```

Then

```
void TabContainer1_ActiveTabChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(TabContainer.ActiveTabIndex == 2){
    //Code hereTabContainer
}
}
```

Comment: In that case event got fired every time whenever user clicks on any tab.I want to fire this event only when user clicks on second tab panel not on first panel click.

Comment: I've find a solution and I'll post answer shortly.